# Mongo exit code 100 in Meteor 0.7.1.2

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I had a perfectly functioning Meteor app. Today, I've updated it from Meteor 0.7.1.1 to 0.7.1.2. Upon starting the app, I get

```
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Can't start Mongo server.
MongoDB had an unspecified uncaught exception.
```

Downgrading to 0.7.1.1 didn't help, nor running `mrt reset`, removing `mongod.lock` file and killing mongo process, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103830/problems-to-run-examples-in-meteor), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610385/meteor-unexpected-mongo-exit-code-100) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877787/meteor-is-not-starting). Is there something that 0.7.1.2 could have broken? What more can I do to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the order of those commands do matter. **First** kill mongo, **then** run `mrt reset`. At least that's what worked for me this time.

Comment: Also, after updating to 0.7.1.2 again the app works fine. So this was probably just a random wandering bug.

Comment: Was you running low on disk space?

Comment: I encountered this too and `ps aux | grep mongo` showed a mongo instance still running.  After killing that meteor was able to start normally.